# How to create a python code that identify seasonality for large dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, time-series, databricks

I need to do a python code (or pyspark in Databricks, if that's possible) that simply identify if my data has or has not seasonal behavior. But I'm mostly finding methods that only generates graphics or just that try to 'correct' the seasonality, tho I just really need to know if the data is or not seasonal.

Basically I have a '.csv' file with three columns "ID", "Month" and "Energy". "ID" is the identification number of a client, "Month" is the month (mm/yyyy) that the client energy has been registered and "Energy" is the energy that has been registered on that specific month. There is various lines for each client, as to register his energy in each month. It is possible to plot the graph of each client and analyze mylself if it has seasonal behavior or not, but there are hundreds of thounsands of clients, so I wanted to have this process being automatic.

Therefore, the idea is to do a code that receives the input dataframe with the 3 columns I mentioned and that returns a new dataframe with 1 column for each "ID" and had the values "Seasonal" or "Not Seasonal".

Anyone knows a method for that in python or pyspark?

I tried to use seasonal_decompose() but I don't quite know how to use the results of this function to do what I want. I've tried searching and using chat gpt, but still kinda lost and wondering if there isn't just a simple (or complex, if needed) solution.